# Forget forwarded emails delivery errors

Tags: email-server, sendmail, email-bounces

I have problem with configuring Sendmail, I've read a lot of topics on the net about similar problems but I didn't found a good answer for this scenario.

Main problem is that my server has poor reputation due to tons of "Unknown Users" at SenderScore.org

**Scenario:**

1. My server receive spam emails for locally existing accounts but
   with prepared Return-Path headers. I want to keep them to avoid loosing emails due to false positives with SpamAssassin checks. Those emails are delivered locally without problems, but...
2. Some users on my server have emails forwarding set to external servers through ".forward" file in their home directory.
3. Those external servers sometimes return errors about temporary delivery problems (not important).
4. My Sendmail sends such error to origin Return-Path address (these prepared).
5. Because mostly those prepared addresses do not exist on those servers my server is reported as a sender of tons of mails to non existing accounts witch causes poor reputation.

**About software:**

1. Linux Centos 6.7
2. Sendmail 8.14.4
3. Mails delivered locally by procmail

**Questions:**

Could you give me some advice how to stop these behavior?

Is there a way to discard delivery bounces produced by trying to delivery mails to ".forward" addresses?

Answer (score 2):

You can choose from the options below:

- integrates [Sender Rewriting Scheme (SRS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Rewriting_Scheme) with sendmail
  I could not find FRESH instructions/milters fast
- disable `~/.forward` files processing in sendmail config and instruct users to use `~/.procmailrc` for forwarding. `~/.procmailrc` does not use original envelope sender by default